# How to increase the number of something using sessions?

Tags: php, session

I want the session increase more number every time I click on a button. The problem is I can not get it to increment. Seemed like it get the same value all the time. The script is below.

```
$no = 1;
session_start();

session_register("sess_id");
$_SESSION['sess_id'][]=$no;

$no++;
```

Comment: You are not incrementing the session variable but some other variable. Increment the session variable instead.

Comment: How to do that ? please show me.

Comment: I [added an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9062124/367456) with some more explanation and links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but I think you're looking for something along the lines of:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['number'])) { /* If there is already a value set */
  $_SESSION['number']++; /* Increment by 1 */
}
else { /* If there is no value set, ie the user is clicking the button for the first time */
  $_SESSION['number'] = 1; /* Set to 1 */
}
```

Comment: The deal is: I want to use the value of session value to do something. And it must be different value. everytimes user click on the button.

Comment: @Alex can you post the _entire_ code for the page so I can see where this piece of code is being called and how it is being used?

Comment: Hi, here is the code:
if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_id'])) $_SESSION['sess_id'] = 0;
 $_SESSION['sess_id']++;

 
            
    for ($i=0;$i<count( $_SESSION["sess_iddd"]);$i++) {
  
   
   
 echo $_SESSION['sess_iddd'][$i];
 }

Comment: I really don´t know why your script is working for me today, but..:)
At least I can close this case ;)

Answer (score 1):

All you *need* to do is increment the value in the `$_SESSION` array:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['no'] = empty($_SESSION['no']) ? 0 : $_SESSION['no'];
$_SESSION['no'] += 1;
```

Comment: no, non of them is working, i got the error message : Warning: Cannot use a scalar v...873     :S

Answer (score 1):

Using session_register is DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['count']=(isset($_SESSION['count']))?$_SESSION['count']+1:0;
?>
```

Comment: so sad, it doses not increse at all :S

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is how you're incrementing your variable.  PHP does not default to assigning variables by reference, so `$_SESSION['sess_id'][] = $no;` is actually assigning by value (in addition to indexing the variable as an integer).  Your subsequent call `$n++` won't alter the value stored in your PHP session.

What I think you want is to [assign by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php), e.g.

```
$no = 1;
session_start();
$_SESSION['your_session_var_name'] =& $no; // value is '1'

$no++; // $no is now '2'
echo $_SESSION['your_session_var_name']; // outputs '2'
```

Comment: it does not work....even i click it in 10 times, the value is still 1. and no incresing.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `session_register` anymore, just use the `$_SESSION` array.

```
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_id'])) $_SESSION['sess_id'] = 0;
 $_SESSION['sess_id']++;
```

Comment: 2 usual suspects: (1) are you calling `session_start()` on _every_ page using the `$_SESSION` array? (2) Are you overwriting the value somewhere? My hunch is 2, but good luck finding where ;)

Comment: yeah, i do it, I call session start in every pages....can u explain me what is wrong ? and what should i do if i need to call session_strat() on every pages ?

Answer (score 0):

When you start a new session all session variables are empty (not set). If you want to increment one of those, you need to create it first if it did not exist -or- if it exists (following requests) increment it:

```
session_start();
if (FALSE === isset($_SESSION['no']))
{
    # session is new
    $_SESSION['no'] = 1;
}
else
{
   # session already exists
   $_SESSION['no']++;
}
```

You can use the [`isset`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/isset) language construct to test if a variable is set or not. In case it is not set (`FALSE`), the session variable is initialized with the value `1`.

In case it exists, the session variable is incremented with the [`++` operator<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

Take care that this is unrelated to session id. It's not necessary for your question to change or set the session id, PHP will do this for you.

I hope this helps you to better understand what you're dealing with as you wrote in a comment above that you have no clue why this works ;)